Is the $k$th covariant derivative of a function $f\colon M\to\mathbb R$ symmetric?
In the flat case ($\mathbb R^N$ with the Euclidean metric) it is true that the $k$th covariant derivative $\nabla^kf$ is symmetric because its coordinates are:
$$(\nabla^kf)_{i_1\ldots i_k}(x)=\dfrac{\partial^kf}{\partial x _{i_1}\cdots\partial x _{i_k}}(x)$$
which are symmetric by the Schwarz Theorem.
In the context of the Riemannian manifold, I am going to use the notation in Chapter 1 of Hebey's book, the $k$-th covariant derivative of a smooth function $f\colon M\to\mathbb R$ is the $k$-covariant tensor with coordinates satisfying the following recursive rule:
$$(\nabla^{k}f)(x)_{i_1\ldots i_k}=\dfrac{\partial(\nabla^{k-1}f) _{i_2\ldots i_k}}{\partial x _{i_1}} (x)-\sum _{\ell=2}^k\Gamma _{i_1i _\ell}^\alpha(x)(\nabla^{k-1}f) _{i_2\ldots i _{\ell-1} \alpha i _{\ell+1} \ldots i_k}(x). $$
My question is: Is the tensor $\nabla^kf$ symmetric?
For $k=2$ we have the Hessian given by
$$(\nabla^2f)_{ij}(x)=\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x _i\partial x _j}(x)-\Gamma _{ij}^k(x)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x _k}(x), $$
which is symmetric by the Schwarz Theorem and the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols.
My try: It is enough to prove for a given permutation that fixes all indexes and only changes just two of them. Let us fix a permutation $\sigma$ with $\sigma(i_a)=i_b$, $\sigma(i_b)=i_a$, and $\sigma(i_\ell)=i_\ell$ for all $\ell\neq a,b$. Since we have a recursive rule for the $k$-th covariant derivative, I am trying to prove it by induction on $k$. Assuming that $\nabla^{k-1}f$ is symmetric, it is not hard to see (in the recursive rule) that $(\nabla^kf) _{\sigma(i_1)\ldots\sigma(i_k)}=(\nabla^kf) _{i_1\ldots i_k}$ for the permutation $\sigma$ with $a,b\neq 1$. Therefore, it is sufficient to prove that $\nabla^kf$ is symmetric in the first two entries, that is
$$(\nabla^kf) _{i_2i_1i_3\ldots i_k}=(\nabla^kf) _{i_1i_2i_3\ldots i_k}.$$
I have no idea how to prove this. Also, I am not sure if this is true. If this is not true in a general manifold, could you (please) check that for the Hyperbolic space? The Hyperbolic case is the case which I need.

Covariant derivatives do not commute.

When $\nabla$ is torsion free (for example Levi-Civita connection) then we have
(see S. Carroll, Spacetime and Geometry)
$$
\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu V^\rho-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\rho=R^\rho{}{\sigma\mu\nu}V^\rho
$$
where $V^\rho$ are the components of a vector field and $R^\rho{}{\sigma\mu\nu}$ those of  the Riemann curvature tensor. This answers fully the question when
$\nabla_\mu$ and $\nabla_\nu$ commute when applied to a vector field.

Correcting a typo: $\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu V^\rho-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu V^\rho=R^\rho{}_{\sigma\mu\nu}V^\color{red}\sigma,.$

An analogous statement applies to the commutator of covariant derivatives when applied to a $1$-form, and in particular to $df = \nabla f$, which immediately answers o.p.'s question in the negative.

The answer is no. We will calculate the components of $\nabla^3f$.
\begin{aligned}
   (\nabla^3f)_{ijk} & =(\nabla^3f)(\partial_i,\partial_j,\partial_k) \\
   & =(\nabla_{\partial_k}(\nabla^2f))(\partial_i,\partial_j) \\
   & =\partial_k((\nabla^2f)(\partial_i,\partial_j))-(\nabla^2f)(\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_i,\partial_j)-(\nabla^2f)(\partial_i,\nabla_{\partial_k}\partial_j) \\
   & =\partial_k(f_{,ij}-f_{,\alpha}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij})-\Gamma^\alpha_{ik}(\nabla^2f)(\partial_\alpha,\partial_j)-\Gamma^\alpha_{jk}(\nabla^2f)(\partial_i,\partial_\alpha) \\
   & =f_{,ijk}-f_{,\alpha k}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}-f_{,\alpha}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij,k}-\Gamma^\alpha_{ik}(f_{,\alpha j}-f_{,\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\alpha j})-\Gamma^\alpha_{jk}(f_{,\alpha i}-f_{,\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\alpha i}) \\
   & =f_{,ijk}-f_{,\alpha k}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}-f_{,\alpha}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij,k}-f_{,\alpha j}\Gamma^\alpha_{ik}-f_{,\alpha i}\Gamma^\alpha_{jk}+f_{,\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\alpha j}\Gamma^\alpha_{ik}+f_{,\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\alpha i}\Gamma^\alpha_{jk}.
\end{aligned}
Switching $j\longleftrightarrow k$, we have
$$(\nabla^3f)_{ikj}=f_{,ikj}-f_{,\alpha j}\Gamma^\alpha_{ik}-f_{,\alpha}\Gamma^\alpha_{ik,j}-f_{,\alpha k}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}-f_{,\alpha i}\Gamma^\alpha_{kj}+f_{,\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\alpha k}\Gamma^\alpha_{ij}+f_{,\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\alpha i}\Gamma^\alpha_{kj}.$$
Observing both, it can be seen that
$$\text{the first items are the same,}$$
$$\text{the second item of one and the fourth item of the other are the same,}$$
$$\text{the fifth items are the same,}$$
$$\text{the seventh items are the same.}$$
The remaining items cannot be offset.

No, in general for a torsion-free affine connection $\nabla$ (in particular, if $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of a Riemmanian metric) and a smooth function $f$, $\nabla^k f$ need not be symmetric for $k \geq 3$, and in fact the failure of symmetry for general functions $f$ is exactly what the curvature $R$ of the curvature encodes.
Recall that the Hessian $(\nabla^2 f)_{ij}$ of a smooth function $f$ is symmetric. So, the third covariant derivative, $(\nabla^3 f)_{ijk}$, is symmetric precisely if the antisymmetrization over the $j, k$ vanishes:
$$0 = (\nabla^3 f)_{i[jk]} = -\frac12R_{jk}{}^l{}_i (\nabla f)_l .$$
Since (pointwise) $\nabla_l f$ takes on arbitrary values in $T^*M$, $\nabla^3 f$ is only symmetric for all $f$ if only if $R \equiv 0$, that is, if $\nabla$ is (locally) flat. In particular, $\nabla^3 f$ is not symmetric for hyperbolic space; using the special form of the curvature for a space form in terms of a metric gives that that asymmetric part of $\nabla^3 f$ on hyperbolic space is a nonzero constant multiple (that depends on the normalization of the scalar curvature) of $g_{i[j} (\nabla f)_{k]}$.
Remark If $\nabla$ is not torsion-free, then even the second covariant derivative $\nabla^2 f$ need not be symmetric. Indeed, antisymmetrizing $(\nabla^2 f)_{ij}$ gives that
$$2 (\nabla^2 f)_{[ij]} = - T^k{}_{ij} (\nabla f)_k ,$$
where $T^k{}_{ij}$ is the torsion of $\nabla$. So, $\nabla^2 f$ is only symmetric for all $f$ if and only if $\nabla$ is torsion-free, i.e., $T \equiv 0$.
